# SQL Handling 2 tables efficiently by Joins

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2012

I have described scenarios where i like to have an efficient 1 SQL Query. I have tried to do using Temporary tables, but i'm finding myself no where. Seeking expert opinions. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I have 2 tables Table A and Table B.

```
    Table A
    ID  TestName    

    Table B
    ID  TableAID LastUpdate
```

TableAID in table B is the ID column of Table A.

Scenario 1 :

```
    Table A
    ID  TestName    
    1   Test 1      

    Table B
    ID  TableAID LastUpdate
```

If Table B does not have any records, then insert all the Table A records to Table B

Scenario 2:

```
    Table A
    ID  TestName    
    1   Test 1      

    Table B
    ID  TableAID LastUpdate
    1   1
```

If Table A has records and matches records in table B, then donot do any action

Scenario 3:

```
    Table A
    ID  TestName 
    1   Test 1  
    2   Test 2      

    Table B
    ID  TableAID LastUpdate
    1   1
```

If Table A has records and not matching in Table B, then insert into Table B

Scenario 4:

```
    Table A
    ID  TestName


    Table B
    ID  TableAID LastUpdate
    1   1
    2   2
```

if Table A has no records, then update current date in LastUpdate in table B for all the records

I' planned to have 2 temprory tables and use Except to filter matching records. But i'm finding it difficult to write an efficient Query.

Comment: Scenario 4 should not happen, and can not happen if you are using foreign keys.

Comment: There is no foreign key reference in Table B. Table A is calculated output and can be treated as Temporary table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a perfect excuse to use [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) command

```
MERGE TableB b
USING TableA a ON a.ID = b.TableAID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (TableAID) VALUES (a.ID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN UPDATE SET LastUpdate = GETDATE();
```

Comment: `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` - Does that mean no records on the source table at all? I suspect you'll have to add another condition for that.

Comment: @ZoharPeled No, that means: for each record in TableB not found in TableA. Not exactly what OP asked, but my guess what's more likely needed. If TableA is empty, that's all records in TableB so it will work in given scenario.

Comment: However... scenario not given in question - if TableB has 2 records, and TableA has 1 matching record - does other TableB row needs to be updated or not. This will update it. If that's not good, this idea will not work.

Comment: @ZoharPeled  scenario 3 is vice versa: two records in A, one record in B?

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic, for scenario you have asked, i always get Table A populated first and then compare with Table B. So if Table A has 2 Records with ID 1 and 2 and and table B also has TableAID 1 and 2, i dont update. If Table A has ID 1 and Table B has only TableAID as 1 and  2, i update getDate table B for TableAID 2 only

Answer (score 0):

For scenarios 1, 2 and 3, seems to me like you just need a simple insert statement with a left join:

```
INSERT INTO [Table B] (TableAId)
SELECT a.ID
FROM [Table A] a
LEFT JOIN [Table B] b ON a.ID = b.TableAId
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```

**Note:** I'm assuming that the `ID` column in `Table B` is an `identity`, and that the `LastUpdate` column is nullable.

This will insert to Table B all the records that exists in Table A but not in Table B.

For senario 4 you need an update statement:

```
UPDATE [Table B]
SET LastUpdate = GETDATE()
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM [Table A]
)
```

I don't see a way for you to do all 4 scenarios in a single query.